# Django 1.4 LocaleMiddleware not working with Apache, but works with runserver

Tags: django, localization, django-middleware, url-pattern

My project has this middleware setting:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)
```

For local development, I setup a `local_settings.py` module which redefines the middleware setting as:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

Here I'm just removing the cache-related middleware, just for development.

In my Apache deploy, the `local_settings.py` only redefines `DEBUG` (to `False`) and the `DATABASES` dict.

I even installed IPython in the project's production virtualenv (the one that the Apache server uses) and executed this:

```
In [1]: from django.conf import settings

In [2]: settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES
Out[2]: 
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')
```

But, despite all this, I still have to enter a language identifier in the URL (as `httpp://mysite.com/en/myview/`) to access any URL that uses `from django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns`. And one of the functions of `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` is to do precisely that, when accessing a localized view without a language code prefix, guess it from the user-agent headers and redirect to the prefixed view.

How to debug what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figure it out (silly problem...) Looking at the code, `django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware` first inspects if the response status code is `404` (Not-Found) and then retries the request with the language code prefixed. But, that code never gets executed... just because I didn't create the `404.html` template, raising an exception, etc...

This also explains why it worked when `DEBUG = True`, because in debug mode the `404.html` template is never used.

Just created the corresponding `404.html` template and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem, but :
I had defined a `handler_404` in my urlconf, pointing to a view.
This view returned an HttpResponse, but with `status_code = 200` instead of 404.
Hence the same problem.

Comment: I set `handler_404` to point to a view I wrote. This view returned a simple HttpResponse (containing information about the page not found). But by default, HttpResponse has an attribute named `status_code` with a value of 200, which means "OK". I had to change the HttpResponse as follows:
`output = render_to_response(...)` and `output.status_code = 404`